# The brush in sculpt mode isn't sensitive enough

Tags: sculpting

I'm new to Blender and learning how to sculpt, and when I try to use my mouse to sculpt it takes multiple passes with the mouse to making any visible indent when the tutorial I'm following can do it in one clean motion. I'm using the default SculptDraw, and the only settings I've changed are setting radius to 25px and strength to 1.000.

Comment: Setting the radius to something larger should increase the effect of the brush

Comment: That seems to have helped, thanks! I figured a smaller radius would be better for this but I guess not lol